# How do I plot a graph with the x axis across the middle?

Tags: graphs

[image: Velocity vs time graph]

I have a huge project for my grade 11 physics class. I've just started using latex and i want to know how to plot a graph but as in the picture shows, the x axis is in the middle of the graph opposed as to the many I've seen online being on either side. Could someone provide me with the exact code for the picture shown?

And if someone can be so kind Could someone provide me with dotted grid lines? Thanks!

Comment: You can use  the `pstricks` package  and its family (`pst-plot`, `pst-node`, &c. Among many, many others, it has `\psgrid` and a `\psaxes` commands; also commands to plot data or functions or parametrised curves. You can take a look at its homepage: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/.

Comment: Forgot to welcome to TeX SX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of different plotting packages for LaTeX, the most popular ones probably being PGFPlots and `pst-plot`. They have different advantages and drawbacks, so it's hard to give a general recommendation which one to use. For straightforward plots like this, any plotting package will be fine.

Here's an example of creating a plot like the one you show in your question using PGFPlots:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left, % The y axis should be on the left border
    axis x line=middle, % The x axis should go through the origin
    grid=both, % Switch on the grid lines
    ytick={-9,-6,...,9}, % Manually specify the tick spacing. By default, PGFPlots will try to use multiples of 1, 2, or 5
    enlarge y limits=true, % Extend the y axis a little bit
    xlabel=$t / \si{\s}$, % Set the x axis label
    xlabel style={anchor=south west},
    ylabel=$v_y / \si{\m\per\s}$, % Set the y axis label
    ylabel style={ % Change the position and rotation of the y axis label
        at={(current axis.above origin)},
        rotate=-90,
        anchor=south west
    }
]
\addplot [thick, black] table {
t     v
0     0
1    -9
1.25  9
3.25 -9
3.5   9
5.5  -9
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why `\mathrm{y}`, it's probably the velocity in _y_-direction, so it should be in italics.
And the units shouldn't be in braces but with a division:
with `siunitx`:
xlabel=$t/\si{\second}$
ylabel=$v_y/\si{\second\per\second}$

Comment: @MaxNoe: You're absolutely right. I was just treating the `y` as a general qualifier. Corrected now. Same for the units.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response Jake! last question what if i wanted to put individual dots instead of the data being connected through lines? and how do i put dotted gridlines?

Comment: @David: To get markers at each data point and no connecting line, use `\addplot [only marks, mark=*, ...]` (or `mark=o` for open circles). To get dotted grid lines, set `grid style=dotted, axis line style=dotted`.

Answer (score 0):

A `pstricks` solution. Loading `auto-pst-pdf`allows for compiling with `pdfLaTeX` with the `--shell-escape` switch (TeX Live, MacTeX), or `--enable-write18`(MiKTeX):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,x11names]{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}%
\savedata{\mydata}[{{0, 0}, {1, -9}, {1.3, 9}, {3.3 ,-9}, {3.5, 9}, {5.5, -9}]
\footnotesize
\psset{unit = 0.9}
\begin{pspicture}[](0, -4.25)(11,4.25)
\psset{gridwidth=1.pt, subgriddiv=1,gridlabels = 0pt, gridcolor = LightSteelBlue1, griddots=8}
\psgrid(0, -4.25)(11.4, 4.25)
\psset{xunit=1.8cm, yunit=0.3cm, ticks=all, ticksize=-2pt 2pt, Dy=3, dy =3, xyDecimals=1}%, labelsep = 0pt
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-11.995)(5.9, 12.6)[\llap{$t$ (s) },-60][$v_y$ (m/s),-140]
\dataplot[plotstyle=lines, linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=DodgerBlue3]{\mydata}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]